# How to create ordered and unordered lists in contenteditable="true"

Tags: javascript, html, ios, dom

I'm trying to create a simple text editor that allows ordered and unordered lists. I understand I can use

```
document.execCommand('InsertOrderedList', false, null);
```

This works fine if the user selects the corresponding button to initiate the task, but how can I detect if the user has entered 1.  at the beginning of a line, I would like to automatically start the list once a user has started a new line with a number . and space

I understand that there are libraries are available to do this. But I'm working with WebKit inside an iOS app and I'm not interested third-party libraries.